# How can I keep the frame rate of Android Camera constant

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camera-intent

I've been working on a project to transmit data through a light transmitter (LED screen) that displays a video with coded information and a photodetector array as the receiver, that is, in this case, an Android Camera composed by a lot of photodiodes.

To execute the data transfer with success, the syncronization between the display rate of frame videos and the capture rate (i.e., frame rate) of the Camera has to be almost perfect.

So, I developed a code that can change and fix the  Android Camera frame rate and does other stuff too. The section that implement the modifications on Camera parameters is shown below:

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(15000,15000);
    parameters.setVideoStabilization(true);
    parameters.setAutoExposureLock(true);
    parameters.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(true);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);


    mCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);        
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280,720);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(25000);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile().toString());

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
```

But even doing that, the syncronization doesn't seems to be working very well, especially because the Android Camera frame rate is not constant. I used the Camera1 API that is already deprecated. So, does anyone knows how can I keep the Android Camera frame rate constant ?

Maybe using Camera2 would be an option, but i don't know how exactly I should start.

Since now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that the device you're using supports that camera frame rate range? It's not guaranteed that just any frame rate pair is supported, there's a list at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#getSupportedPreviewFpsRange() that tells you what any particular camera device supports.

Usually, you can rely on `[30,30]` being available, but other fixed frame rates may not be.

There are some Android camera implementations that take the preview FPS range as more of a hint than a requirement, though that is against the API specification.  But most recent devices do what they're told if you ask for a fixed rate via setPreviewFpsRange.

Using Camera2 wouldn't help here, since the same set of supported frame rates would apply to the same camera device from camera2 as well.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. The device I'm using is Moto G7 play, from Lenovo. By what I checked, this smartphone supports the values of 15 and 30 for frame rate. I guess I will try using 30 fps, because it's the native fps from it. Another problem that I realized is that the shutter speed, ISO and exposure settings from my camera can affect the system that I'm trying to implement. I will try to improve these parameters to get the best and stable fps as possible.

Comment: When you say 15, do you mean getSupportedPreviewFpsRange returns [15,15]? If so, then it should work as you expect. That said, the old camera API doesn't really have any controls over shutter speed or ISO, so you may need to move to camera2 if you wanted to control those yourself.

Comment: I guess it is. Basically for my project works, the camera has to record at a constant frame rate, with a few (or none, in an ideal world) frame drops. Is that what getSupportedPreviewFPsRange returns [15,15] means ? About the other parameters, I believe it won't be necessary to change, the default is fine by now. The only other thing I will change is the resolution.